# Data context is null , template is loaded before collection is ready

Tags: meteor

```
Router.route('/form/:_id', function () {

      this.render('viewForm', {
        data: function () {
          return forms.findOne({id: this.params._id});
        },
      waitOn:function(){
         return Meteor.subscribe("forms").ready();
        }
      });
    }
    ,
     {name:"forms.show",
      layoutTemplate: 'generalLayout'

      });
```

the data context is empty when i open the link on a new private window .
here's my template manager side

```
    Meteor.subscribe("forms");
Template.viewForm.rendered = function(){
    console.log("calling view form");
    currentForm = this.data;
    console.log("form id",currentForm.id);

}
```

when i reload the page the dat is retrieved .

here's my loading template with the spin package

```
<template name="loadingTemplate">
  {{>spinner}}
</template>

    Router.configure({
 loadingTemplate: 'loadingTemplate',
 layoutTemplate: 'generalLayout'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the subscribe method into the route,using `waitOn` function, like this, just to be sure that `template` wait until the collection is ready

```
waitOn:function(){
 return Meteor.subscribe("forms");
}
```

Also don't forget to use a `loading template` with the `waitOn` function.

```
 Router.configure({
 loadingTemplate: 'loadingTemplate',
 layoutTemplate: 'generalLayout',
 waitOn:function(){
     return Meteor.subscribe("forms");
    }
});
```

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: you have a loading template?

Comment: no i don't have a loading template it's just a viewForm template i rendeer , i send the link to the user via Email , and when i click on a private new window , the data context is null.

Comment: @Genjuro Frankly, the `waitOn` feature will not work until you have that `loadingTemplate` defined.

Comment: i have set up a loading template and still it doesn't work , i'm sure the templat egets rendered way before the collection is ready , i'll update my code

Comment: solved it , i add added to wait on in the router configuration :)